# MapStruct: How to map to existing target?

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have a method in a service that updates an entity. It accepts object that has the data to update the entity. Dto object has less fields than entity but the fields have the same names.

Could it be possible to use mapstruct for that routine job by passing an existing target object?

```
class Entity {
  id
  name
  date
  country
  by
  ... //hell of the fields
}
class UpdateEntity {
  name
  country
  ... //less but still a lot
}

class EntityService {
  update(UpdateEntity u) {
    Entity e = // get from storage
    mapstructMapper.mapFromTo(u, e)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide a compilable code first.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis it would be easier to copy and paste, but nobody should do that from a question) The field names doesn't matter here. And all the java syntax with access modifiers and return types would make it messier I believe. It is a question about java, though)

Comment: You might be surprized that most of the people copy+paste the question code and try to find out a solution in the ID. At least the class and method definitions would be complete. Take a look at here: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Yes, all you need to do is define a `Mapper` with an `update` method, something like:

```java
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.MappingTarget;

@Mapper
public interface EntityMapper {
  void update(@MappingTarget Entity entity, UpdateEntity updateEntity);
}
```

Please, review the relevant [documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#updating-bean-instances).

By default, Mapstruct will map every matching property in the source object to the target one.

Comment: I am trying to use the same strategy with collections, but it doesn't work :\

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @gursahib.singh.sahni. Please, could you elaborate your problem? How are you trying to update your collections? Could you further explain your use case?